# Django hash password

Tags: django

I use django.contrib.auth

My problem: login wont work because the password is saved in clear, when I go in admin or in the shell I can see the password in clear text. If I manually use User.set_password() in the shell, then I can login.

So, why the password is saved in clear and not automatically hashed?

Is there a way to hash it when creating a user?

I extend the default User to add attributes.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profil(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    facebook_profil = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Then I have a register and a login forms :

```
from django import forms
from members.models import Profil


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profil
        exclude = ("is_staff", "groups", "is_active", "is_superuser", 
                   "user_permissions", "last_login", "date_joined")
        fields = ["username", "password", "first_name", "last_name", "email", 
                 "postal_code", "facebook_profil", "make", "model", "year", "photo"]

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Nom d'utilisateur", max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Mot de passe", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

And finally I have a CreateView and a LoginView to register and login the user :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Profil
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class Register(CreateView):
    template_name = "members/register.html"
    model = Profil
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

class Login(LoginView):
    form = LoginForm
    template_name = "members/login.html"
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You shouldn't extend the `User` model in the profile model.

Comment: @PeterSobhi why not? How would you best establish a relationship between User and Profile?

Comment: @DDRRpy By extending `User` you create a duplication in the database. Instead, you should extend `AbstractBaseUser`. You can also create a one to one relationship between `User` and `Profile` models.
Check this article for more information: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `RegisterForm` is saving the password in plain text to the `password` field. You need to set the password properly using `set_password()` before the form is saved:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

This is taken from Django's [`UserCreationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L115-L120).

That, the way you have set up your `Profil` model is very strange and likely tolead to other problems. It doesn't make sense to subclass `User` in that model. You either need to extend the `AbstractUser` and then instruct Django to use this [own custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), or specify a profile model that doesn't subclass `User`, but only has a one-to-one relationship to it.